# email send fail in php using mail

Tags: php, smtp

What error should it be here:

But i have the same syntax as required.What can be the error?

Comment: Are you try to send mail from your local server?

Comment: use phpmailer. because mail() is not working on all hosts.

Comment: yes, from the local server

Comment: then use SMTPmail.

Comment: Did you configure your local host to send mail?

Comment: What? Your question is rather unclear, what isn't working? What errors are you getting?